# What do you do when bootstrap sample gives a numerically "bad" set of samples?

Tags: bootstrap

What do you do when bootstrapping and the sample for one iteration is "bad" in some way that makes your statistic uncomputable.

For example suppose your statistic was the best fit linear slope for a data set of points $(x_i,y_i)$, but your boot strap sample picked points all at the same $x$ coordinate (or even just picked the same point every time).

Does one just throw that sample out?  Is there a method where you put more constraints on how you sample when your statistic needs the sample set to have some property?

I don't have a particular application in mind, this question has just been in the back of my mind for some time.

Edit: I guess I can add a little more context since I'm asking about possible alternatives/work a rounds too.  In my life, the place I use statistics is usually when taking time series data and fitting a model, but a "best fit" usually doesn't come with std err for parameter estimates.  A lot of the time you just plot the fit and hand wave that it "looks good" but it's always bugged me that a std error for paramaters in those fits is not available.

Comment: What we call the "bootstrap" nowadays is a wide array of sampling techniques, and methods for analyzing the samples. But if you are referring to a simple, unconditional, empirical bootstrap - i.e. just randomly sampling rows and looking at the resulting distribution - then no you can't throw those results out. Some quantities are physically unbootstrappable - meaning the result is not at all reliable.

Comment: I don't have any experience in this area, so another can probably give a much more informed answer. Your example makes me think a jackknife estimator would be the better option.

Comment: The odds of this happening, if the bootstrap is properly coded, are infinitessimal.

Comment: @Peter On the contrary, the example provided in the question itself has a finite (albeit small) probability of at least $n^{1-n}$ with $n$ data pairs.  The probability can be appreciable when there are ties in the $x_i,$ potentially with a probability as high as $2^{1-n}$ (when the data are in two equal-sized groups according to two distinct values of $x_i.$) Of course all these values are *negligible* in any application that is theoretically justified, because $n\gg 0$ is essential for the bootstrap. In other circumstances, though, even with "proper coding" there can be problems.